# Resolving dependency depending on generic type - Autofac

Tags: autofac

I have a generic class (`GenericClass`)  which is having a dependency depending on the generic type (`IGenericDependency`). This dependency is also generic.

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
      private readonly IGenericDependency;
}
```

The type parameter is not known until runtime.

So far I've done this:

I'm injecting a Func.

```
public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T> where T:class , new()
{
      private readonly IGenericDependency _genericDependency;

      public GenericClass(Func<TypeIGenericDependency>> factory)
      {
            _genericDependency = factory(T);
      }
}
```

And the reistration code:

```
  builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (GenericClass<>)).As(typeof (IGenericClass<>));

  builder.Register<Func<Type, IGetDataCollection>>(c =>
  {
        var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return type =>
               {
                    if(type.Name.EndsWith("Entity"))
                    {
                        return (IGenericDependency)
                           context.Resolve(typeof (GetEntityCollection<>)
                           .MakeGenericType(type));
                    }
                    if(type.Name.EndsWith("TypedList"))
                    {
                        return (IGenericDependency)
                           context.Resolve(typeof (GetTypedList<>)
                           .MakeGenericType(type));
                    }
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Not supported type");
                };
  });
```

I'm wondering if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a recent build, you can use make `IGenericDependency` generic, e.g. `IGenericDependency<T>` then use generic type constraints to discriminate between the implementations:

```
public class GetTypedList<T> : IGenericDependency<T>
    where T : TypedList {
}

public class GetEntity<T> : IGenericDependency<T>
    where T : Entity {
}
```

`GenericClass<T>` then depends directly on `IGenericDependency<T>`.

So long as `TypedList` and `Entity` are mutually exclusive types, Autofac will choose the correct implementation.

HTH

Comment: Wow, I knew there must be some neater solution :-) This saves a lot of code. Should be as an example in the wiki.